# Let $x\in (0,1)$ then check for convergence or divergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $x\in(0,1)$ then check for convergence or divergence of series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{\sqrt{n}}$$

It seems to be convergent but I am having problem in showing that. Every test is seems to fail. Any hint is careful.

Comment: $e^{-\sqrt n t} \leq \frac {4!} {(\sqrt n t)^{4}}$ where $t =-\ln x$

Comment: Hint, which is close to the previous one: notice that $x^t < \frac{1}{t^2}$ for $t \ge t_0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks sir.i got it

Answer (score 1):

Divide the summation into blocks from $m^2$ to $(m+1)^2$. Each block has $2m + 1$ items and the largest is the first one, so the sum of elements in the block can be estimated by
$(2m + 1)x^m$. But this series converges by ratio (d'Alambert) test.